# how does TPC-H query performace involving string pattern matching predicates drastically improved in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I recently upgraded my machine from PostgreSQL8.3 to PostgreSQL9.3.4. After upgrade, when I ran TPC-H queries for performance testing, I could see drastic change in timings. Especially TPC-H query 5 which was taking 4 minutes to execute in pgsql8.3, took just 15 seconds in postgresql9.3.4. I think the reason it was taking 4 minutes in earlier version was because of the error in selectivity of string pattern matching predicate in the query. How was it fixed in recent version? Has any new algorithm been incorporated to handle this?

Comment: I would suggest the PostgreSQL release notes, one by one.

Comment: Plus: string-handling is relatively unimportant. Fetching the pages from disk is expensive; CPU is cheap.

Comment: Compare the query plans - might be informative.

Comment: Query plan in 8.3 uses many nested loops where as in 9.3 all joins used hash join for that query.

Comment: You are aware that Postgres 8.3 is *very old* by now? There are [5 major releases between 8.3 and 9.3](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), all of them introduced *many* improvements. You won't find a single reason, but a whole set of reasons for the improvement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The algorithm used for string pattern matching in queries involving LIKE clause may have been modified in PostgreSQL9.1. Since then LIKE queries have better selectivity estimation compared to earlier in postgresql.